# CakePHP: command cake server hangs on xampp

Tags: cakephp

I have a basic XAMPP install on windows 10, and I've installed cakePHP, with no errors.

When I run bin/cake server in the xampp terminal, it tells me it's started on localhost:8765, and that I can press CTRL-C to return. It hangs here, shell goes unresponsive, and trying to hit localhost:8765 in the browser hangs indefinitely.

I can view the apache page at localhost:80, with no issue. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Im almost definetly sure, that you have debugging turned on somewhere, and PHP script hangs on first line. Do you have any IDE opened during that procedure? If so, close it, restart php server and try again. It should work now.

I had similar WTFs working with PHPStorm, that unwanted debugging sessions was paused on "script first line" exposing behavior you have described.

Comment: I don't have any IDE's installed, or any kind of debugger.  Would antivirus cause this issue as well?

Comment: Is PHP working at all? Try to run simple script with `phpinfo()` in it.

Comment: phpinfo() returns all the standard stuff, and i'm able to install composer fine.